# Finding values from an ArrayList of ints in an ArrayList of objects with int fields without LINQ

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

I have two ArrayLists of different lengths. One contains ints, the other contains objects containing an int field. I want to check if any values from the list of ints appear as values of the int fields in any of the objects in the second list: eg. if

```
intList[i] == objList[j].value
```

for any i or j.

I'm using .NET 2.0, so I can't use LINQ. Thanks!

Comment: You should use generic lists.

Comment: You can use Linq to Objects with LinqBridge - http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `HashSet<int>` does not exists in 2.0 (if I remember correctly) use Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, object> dic = new Dictionary<int, object>(objList.Count);
foreach (object obj in objList)
    dic.Add(obj.value, null);
bool found = false;
foreach (int i in intList)
{
    if(dic.ContainsKey(i))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to change the "var" as it's not in 2.0, but otherwise this works fine. Thanks!